# Correcting more then one element in a function

Tags: javascript, function

I currently try to write a function that corrects mistakes. S, I, O are misinterpreted as 5, 1, 0 and the function automatically corrects these mistakes.

```js
function correctMistakes1(inputString) {
  let returnString2 = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
    if (inputString.includes('5') && inputString.includes('0') && inputString.includes('1')) {
      replacement = inputString.replace('5', 'S').replace('0', 'O').replace('1', 'I');
      returnString2.correctedString = replacement;
    }
  }

  return returnString2;

}

console.log(correctMistakes1('Hell0 W0rld my name 1s Lar5'))
```

The function works for one 0, one 1 and one 5 but it can't correct a second 0. How can I make it look over every possible 0... and correct it?

Comment: Once you make the fix in the link above your question, you'll also find that you don't need that `for` loop, as `.replace()` (and `.replaceAll()`) will "loop" through your string for you and replace the appropriate characters.